# cgo: calling from a C function located in some package to another

Tags: go

I am trying to follow the guidelines to organize my code with packages and C files located in these directories should be detected and compiled by the tool. However, when I try to reference a function from another package (e.g. calling bar from foo), I am getting the following error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Directories and files:

```
test/main.go

test/bar:
bar.c  bar.go bar.h

test/foo:
foo.c  foo.go foo.h
```

bar.h:

```
extern void bar();
```

bar.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bar() {
  printf("bye\n");
}
```

bar.go:

```
package bar

//#include "bar.h"
import "C"

func Bar() {
    C.bar()
}
```

foo.h:

```
extern void foo();
```

foo.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "../bar/bar.h"

void foo() {
  printf("hello\n");
  bar();
}
```

foo.go:

```
package foo

//include "foo.h"
//include "../bar/bar.h"
import "C"

func Foo() {
    C.foo()
}
```

main.go:

```
package main

import "github.com/user/test/foo"
import "github.com/user/test/bar"


func main() {
  foo.Foo()
  bar.Bar()
}
```

And the output:

```
cd test ; go build     
# github.com/user/test/foo
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_bar", referenced from:
      _foo in foo.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: Its because you need to tell the C compiler which files to compile. When it tries to compile foo.c there is no compiled bar() function. Try to compile your C code separately into static C library and then include it into your GO project.

Comment: I suppose I could. The problem I have with this approach is the fact that 'go build' is supposed to remove the need for Makefile and such from the process of building application. Would bringing everything in one dir fix this limitation since the .c files would be compiled and linked in one ".a" file?

Comment: If you put all files in one directory and package it will work. But for more complex projects I strongly recommend to use separately C and GO building tool chains. CGO is just a way to create C-bindings, not to compile C code.